# Can't see how this function is differentiable Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds Exercise 2-4

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The problem is as follows:

Let $g$ be a continuous real-valued function on the unit circle $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lvert x \rvert = 1\}$ such that $g(0,1) = g(1,0) = 0$ and $g(-x) = -g(x)$. Define $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$f(x) =
          \begin{cases}
           \lvert x \rvert \cdot g\left(\frac{x}{\lvert x \rvert}\right) & : x \neq 0\\
            0 & : x = 0
           \end{cases}$$

The question is: If $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $h(t) = f(tx)$, show that $h$ is differentiable.

I'm not sure which definition of differentiation I should use–the usual single variable one or the general one defined in the chapter? I went with the single variable definition since $h$ is a single variable function and I get:

$$\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{h(t+k) -h(t)}{k} = \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{f((t+k)x) - f(tx)}{k} = \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{\lvert tx-kx \rvert \cdot g\left( \frac{tx-kx}{\lvert tx-kx \rvert} \right) - \lvert tx \rvert \cdot g\left( \frac{tx}{\lvert tx \rvert} \right)}{k}$$

I don't know what to do after this. We don't know if g is differentiable. If I use the other limit definition, I run into the same problem. If the information given for $g$ is supposed to somehow imply that $g$ is differentiable, I don't see it. Any hints?

Comment: Here $f$ is linear on each ray starting at the origin, and since $g$ is odd, $f$ is linear on each line through the origin.  So $h$ is actually linear, hence differentiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that $h(t)=t|x| g(\frac{x}{|x|})$ when $x\neq0$ and $h(t)=0$ when $t=0$. Now notice that $h(t)$ is linear in '$t$'. Hence differentiable. You can even use the definition of differentiablity to show this if you want.

Comment: Why does linearity imply differentiability? $\lim \frac{f(x + h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim \frac{f(x) +f(h) -f(x)}{h} = \lim \frac{f(h)}{h} = \lim \frac{hf(1)}{h} = f(1)?$

Comment: Well any linear function $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ must be differentiable. (Any linear function must be of the form $ax+b$ and.........) In your case, it is clear that $h$ is differentiable when $ t\neq 0$ (Do you see this?). So all you really need to check is the differentiability at $t=0$. This is easy. limit of $\frac{h(k)-h(0)}{k}$ exists as $k$ goes to zero.

Comment: Oh wow. I completely missed the obvious point about linear functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Thanks for making this crystal clear.